# Cordova project - deploy on any browser

Tags: cordova, google-chrome

Is it possible to send my project to another person and run it on another browser (or chrome browser) without that person has to use the "cordova run browser" command from the cordova command CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

do you use gulp ? 
If yes you can run it in the browser with : gulp serve